sqlalchemy IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed sqlite3
I'm working on comments with replies using a self referential relationship. The first comment always submits. The second comment or replies to the first comment fail. I've dropped and recreated the DB, same error occurs.
Error:
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: comment.post_id
[SQL: UPDATE comment SET post_id=? WHERE comment.id = ?]
[parameters: (None, 1)]

models.py
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    body: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.Text)
    user_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey('user.id'), index=True)
    author: so.Mapped['User'] = so.relationship(back_populates='posts')
    comments: so.Mapped['Comment'] = so.relationship(back_populates='post')

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    body: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.Text)
    author_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey('user.id'), index=True)
    author: so.Mapped['User'] = so.relationship(back_populates='comments')
    post_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey('post.id'), index=True)
    post: so.Mapped['Post'] = so.relationship(back_populates='comments')
    parent_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey('comment.id'), nullable=True)
    replies: so.Mapped['Comment'] = so.relationship('Comment')

routes.py
@bp.route('/post/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post(id):
    post = db.first_or_404(sa.select(Post).where(Post.id == id))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('submit') == 'comment':
            comment = Comment(body=request.form.get('body'), post=post, author=current_user._get_current_object(), post_id=id, author_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(comment)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(request.referrer)
        elif request.form.get('submit') == 'reply_comment':
            # The ID for this route is Comment.id not Post.id as default
            comment = db.session.execute(sa.select(Comment).where(Comment.id == id)).scalar()
            post = db.session.execute(sa.select(Post).where(Post.id == comment.post_id)).scalar()
            if comment and post:
                reply_comment = Comment(body=request.form.get('body'), post=post, author=current_user._get_current_object(), post_id=post.id, author_id=current_user.id, parent_id=comment.id)
                db.session.add(reply_comment)                                       
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect(request.referrer)



It doesn't really make sense that your error is an UPDATE sql error but your code is only adding (creating/inserting) comments and replies - which should create INSERT sql. No clue about it ... just weird - or I'm reading the code wrong.
